# Expected list-like value, got string

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have written a keyword which calls a sub-keyword. Now the sub keyword is returning two values which I am trying to store it in an array assigned to main keyword. When I log to console the returned values, it gives an error message saying - Expected list-like value, got string

I have tried the below workarounds(failed):

```
1. Attempt1:
@{Items1}    Run keyword if    '${INACTIVEStateCount}'!='0'    INACTIVE OTOID selector    ${StateCount}
Log To console  Values are ${Items1}

2. Attempt2:
@{Items1}    Run keyword if    '${INACTIVEStateCount}'!='0'    INACTIVE OTOID selector    ${StateCount}
${Items2}   Create List    @{Items1}
Log To console  Values are ${Items2}

Main keyword:

@{Items1}    Run keyword if    '${INACTIVEStateCount}'!='0'    INACTIVE OTOID selector    ${StateCount}
${Items2}    Create List    @{Items1}
Log To console    Values are ${Items2}

SubKeyword:

INACTIVE OTOID selector
    [Documentation]    Used to select Inactive OTOIDs
    [Arguments]    ${StateCount}    ${LocatorWaitTime}=${defaultWait time}
    :FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    ${StateCount}
    \    ${Check}=    Run keyword and return status    Page should contain element     xpath=//*@id='lookupFiberDetailsResult']/table/tbody/tr[${INDEX}]/td[4][text()='INACTIVE']
    \    ${OTO_IDStatus}    Run keyword if    '${Check}'=='True'    Get Text             xpath=//*[@id='lookupFiberDetailsResult']/table/tbody/tr[${INDEX}]/td[4][text()='INACTIVE']
    \    Log to Console    Loop${INDEX} - OTOID:${OTO_IDStatus}
    \    ${OTO_ID}    Run keyword if    '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'   Get Text         xpath=//*[@id='lookupFiberDetailsResult']/table/tbody/tr[${INDEX}]/td[2]               
    \    ${LineIdentifier}    Run keyword if    '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'  Get Text    xpath=//*[@id='lookupFiberDetailsResult']/table/tbody/tr[${INDEX}]/td[1]             
    \    Run keyword if    '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'    Log to Console                  OTOID is: ${OTO_ID}
    \    Run keyword if    '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'    Log to Console                  OTOID is: ${LineIdentifier}
    \    Run Keyword If    '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'    [Return]    ${OTO_ID}
    \    Run Keyword If    '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'    [Return]    ${LineIdentifier}
    \    Exit For Loop if  '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'
```

What I intend to achieve:
I am making the sub-keyword return two values: OTOID and LineIdentifier and store it in an array. And then use these two values separately for further use.

Actual:
When I log to console the values stored in array then I get an error saying:
Expected list-like value, got string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to store the return values from the sub keyword as an array/list but returning strings from it.

```
*** Keywords ***
Main keyword
    ${OTO_ID}    ${LineIdentifier}    Run keyword if    '${INACTIVEStateCount}'!='0'    INACTIVE OTOID selector    ${StateCount}

INACTIVE OTOID selector
    Return From Keyword If    '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'   ${OTO_ID}  ${LineIdentifier}
```

This will return the values `${OTO_ID}` and `${LineIdentifier}` as individual variables and not arrays.

Please note that I've ignored the other steps in the sub keyword just to make the answer simpler.

The line(s) that needs to be replaced:

```
Run Keyword If    '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'    [Return]    ${OTO_ID} 
Run Keyword If    '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'    [Return]    ${LineIdentifier}
```

**Update:**
If you want to strictly return the values as list, use below code

```
*** Keywords ***
Main keyword
    ${Identifiers}    Run keyword if    '${INACTIVEStateCount}'!='0'    INACTIVE OTOID selector    ${StateCount}

INACTIVE OTOID selector
    ${Identifiers}    Create List
    .
    <Your FOR loop here>
    .
    \ Run Keyword If    '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'   Append to List  ${identifiers}    ${OTO_ID}    ${LineIdentifier}
    Exit For Loop If  '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'

    Return From Keyword If    '${OTO_IDStatus}'!='None'    ${Identifiers}
```

Reference : [Robot User guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#user-keyword-return-values)